# What is wrong with the choice of ε for the specific data?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

When I use DBSCAN to cluster data, a group of data is abnormal.

The big integers below are the timestamps of a group of Timestamp.
I try to cluster all records in 40 seconds.

When I try the eps=20, get the abnormal group:
->`array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64)`
When I try the eps=23, get the right answer:
->`array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)`

```
data=[1565541521.0,
    1565541521.0,
    1565541521.0,
    1565541522.0,
    1565541522.0,
    1565541522.0,
    1565541522.0]

df=pd.DataFrame([data],index=['A']).T    
dbscan=DBSCAN(eps=20,min_samples=3).fit(df)
print(dbscan.labels_)
```

Could someone tell me what is wrong with my eps choice and why?

Answer (score 0):

Followed by the documentation:

> eps : 
>       The maximum distance between two samples for one to be considered as in the neighborhood of the other. This is not a maximum bound on the distances of points within a cluster. This is the most important DBSCAN parameter to choose appropriately for your data set and distance function.

and based on the explanation on wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN:

> Consider a set of points in some space to be clustered. Let ε be a parameter specifying the radius of a neighborhood with respect to some point. For the purpose of DBSCAN clustering, the points are classified as core points, (density-)reachable points and outliers, as follows:
>
> A point p is a core point if at least minPts points are within distance ε of it (including p).
>
> A point q is directly reachable from p if point q is within distance ε from core point p. Points are only said to be directly reachable from core points
>   .
>   A point q is reachable from p if there is a path p1, ..., pn with p1 = p and pn = q, where each pi+1 is directly reachable from pi. Note that this implies that all points on the path must be core points, with the possible exception of q.
>
> All points not reachable from any other point are outliers or noise points.
>
> Now if p is a core point, then it forms a cluster together with all points (core or non-core) that are reachable from it. Each cluster contains at least one core point; non-core points can be part of a cluster, but they form its "edge", since they cannot be used to reach more points

So in your case, with the increase in e, you only reduce to one  core point (class 0), your cluster is to broad.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My data is 3 of 1565541521.0 and 4 of 1565541522.0. So the third 1565541521.0 is a core point(min Pts is 3). Because the eps is 20 and the other 4 `1565541522.0`(the distance is only 1) are within distance eps from the core point above, they are **directly** reachable from the core point above. So the dataset is in one group. But DBSCAN divided them into 2 groups.